# Placeholder arguments for Python function

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I currently use the following logic for a function: If I give an account name as an argument, the function should use the account name for the operation. If I do not give this argument, it should open a certain file to go through the accounts in the .txt

In the code I used the argument account='p' ('p' for 'placeholder') but is there a better or more pythonic way to do this?

```
def build_df(account='p'):
    if account == 'p':
        with open('accounts.txt') as f:
            do something with accounts
    else:
        do something with account
```

Comment: `None` sounds like the best choice

Comment: It's also called a default parameter, not placeholder

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "None"?

Comment: The `parameter=value` is the *default value* to be used if nothing is provided to the function call.  If there is not a (safe) default to use, an arbitrary ‘placeholder’ can make the code more difficult to interpret (by maintainers). Therefore a default value should not be set.

Comment: *"What exactly do you mean with "None"?"* — Literally `None`. `None` is Python's "placeholder value" for "nothing", "no value", "undefined".

Comment: Not `"None"`, but `None`. Just do: `account=None`, and then you can test, `if account is None:`